# Will open data foster a common set of "metadata" standards?

Tags: metadata

[This](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-i-can-get-list-of-licenses-used-in-data-gov/4309#4309) is just one example, but I'm sure that there can be many others.

Government open data will have links to all the relevant license information, which will be found in the metadata. That represents an information "standard."

Does this apply only to "open data" produced by the government, or are such standards mandated for privately gathered open data sets as well?

More to the point, is there, or will there be a push for "non" open data sets to source e.g. licensing information in the same, or similar fashion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our hope with the [Frictionless Data](http://frictionlessdata.io/) project is to create a set of standards that apply equally to open and non-open datasets.  These standards did, in fact, grow out of experience with distributing open data.

Check out the Data Package spec here: http://specs.frictionlessdata.io/data-packages/